# Norm of connection form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I'm working through the paper [Carleman estimates for geodesic X-ray transforms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02163) by GP Paternain and M Salo; this question concerns that paper.  I'm including page references, but I don't see any reason why one would need to consult the paper.

Setup: $A$ is the connection form of a connection $\mathcal{E}$ on the trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb{C}^n$ over a Riemannian manifold $M$.

The paper references the quantity $\|A\|_{L^\infty(M)}$ (top of p. 28) without definition/explanation; I'm looking for some insight on how to parse/interpret this combination of symbols.

According to the subscript on the norm, they want us to consider $A$ as a function on M - which is consistent with the statement $A \in C^\infty(M,(\Lambda^1 M)^{n\times n})$ that appears where $A$ is introduced, look at "the norm" - see Q1 below - of each $A(p)$, and take the biggest (up to a set of msr 0 etc).

**Questions:**

1. Is there a standard way to norm a matrix of tangent/cotangent vectors?  Is it the Frobenius norm of the matrix whose entries are the norms of the original entries?
2. Separate from what they're doing, is there a standard notion for the norm of a connection form?
3. *Technically*, $A\in\Omega^1(M)^{n\times n}$ - the difference being that one is a matrix of "functions" (1-forms) and the other is a function that spits out matrices; their way looks at it as a pointwise object, whereas philosophically it wants to be more of a gestalt IMO.  If indeed there is different a notion of norm for a connection form, is it possible that the way they've chosen to look at $A$ implicitly points to the appropriate notion of norm?

**Edit:** Since the connection form depends on choice of frame field and they don't fix a choice of frame field, I'm guessing whatever norm they're working with doesn't depend on this choice?